# How to create a bootable USB key of Sierra, from High Sierra?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, bootable-disk

I have a 2018 MBP running High Sierra.  I need to do some troubleshooting on another older Mac that is running Sierra, so I want to create a bootable USB key of Sierra.  Unfortunately my High Sierra MBP won't allow me to run the Sierra installer, saying:

> This copy of the “Install macOS” application is too old to be opened
>   on this version of macOS.

Is there any way to create a Sierra bootable USB key, from a machine running High Sierra?

Comment: what command are you issuing to create the USB disk

Comment: None, I just want to run the Sierra installer and choose the USB drive as the target for installing onto.  The disk is formatted Extended Journaled with GUID scheme.

Comment: So you downloaded the Sierra and used `sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app` to create bootable Sierra USB disk. If your drive is named something else, you need to change Untitled to the name of your drive.

Comment: No, I am not doing anything in terminal.  I'm not looking to make a bootable installer, which I think is what you're talking about doing.  I want an actual bootable drive running Sierra so that I can run other apps from it.

Comment: The above command will take the Sierra that you downloaded to your High Sierra Mac, and it will create Sierra USB. Now you can use that USB and run your Sierra Mac from it.

Comment: But isn't that just creating a bootable installer (createinstallmedia)?  I don't want a bootable installer, I want a normal bootable drive.  Will this somehow give me that?

Comment: OK it finished, but all I get is a USB drive called "Install macOS Sierra" with nothing but the installer on it.  There is no system on the drive.  Booting from the drive confirms it is a bootable installer, which is not what I need.

Comment: I am sorry that was total misunderstanding on my end.

Comment: No worries, though you had me excited for a moment.  LOL . Looks like I'll just have to resort to installing onto this drive from another older Mac running Sierra already.  It should work but the last time I tried this it took a good 2 days to finish since the old Mac USB is so incredibly slow.  Oh well, guess that's just the way it goes.  Thanks for the effort!

Comment: did you try copying Sierra Installer (5GB) to the USB and then try to run it form there to make it install the OSX to USB ?, hopefully it wont look at your High Sierra

Comment: Well damn, that didn't work.  Got weird errors and a reboot loop along the way so I stopped it.  No idea why I can't get Sierra installed onto a USB key.  Oh and the installer still won't run if the OS in use is High Sierra, that's what matters... not what volume the installer was launched from.

Comment: How damaged is this older Mac? Can't you boot the bootable installer on it and create the second "USB key" with the system that way on the older Mac?

Comment: I don't have a second USB key large enough to make that work.  But there is an external drive on it with what should be a bootable Sierra.  I'll be giving that a try next, I was mostly hoping the process of making the bootable key would be a whole lot faster on the newer machine.  Old machine is in an uncertain state.  Woke up to it this morning being completely crashed for no reason I can see.  Will boot off its external drive and see where I'm at.